# Definition of direct products of two cones or of two convex subsets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

When reading a comment after [this reply](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/5570/258), I was wondering what the definitions of direct product of two cones?

More generally, what is the direct product of two convex subsets? This case is what I found by googling ([here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.5/share/doc/Macaulay2/Polyhedra/html/_direct__Product.html) and [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.5/share/doc/Macaulay2/Polyhedra/html/___Cone_sp_st_sp__Cone.html)), but I haven't found the definitions yet.

Is there a more general definition?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

As a set, the direct product $C_1\times C_2$ of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is just the set of ordered couples $\left\{(c_1,c_2)\mid c_1\in C_1, c_2\in C_2\right\}$. Moreover, if $C_1$ and $C_2$ have some additional structure, usually their product can be endowed with the same kind of structure, for example that of [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_space). This is true for [convexity](http://www.ece.ust.hk/~eeyw/opt09/L2.pdf), too.

---

You are asking about a more general definition, too. The most general definition of (direct) product I can think of is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29), but I'll just link to it as a reference. Just notice that some mathematicians would call that kind of language "abstract nonsense". ;)

Comment: Thanks! So it is the same as Cartesian product?

Comment: Yes, Cartesian product is direct product of sets. If those sets have additional structure which is preserved by taking the product, you call it (direct) product (of topological spaces, vector spaces, etc).